# nginx+ubuntu+sugarcrm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sugarcrm

Does anyone have good instructions on how to install SugarCRM on Ubuntu using nginx? I am looking to install SugarCRM on 8.04 (Hardy Heron) LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's trivial: `apt-get install nginx` + [Sugar Community Edition 5.2 Documentation: Installation Process](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/5.2/-docs-Administration_Guides-CommunityEdition_Install_Admin_Guide_5.1-Sugar_Install.3.3.html)